# Fill missing date values in column by adding delivery interval to another date column

Tags: r, dataframe, date-format, missing-data, date-arithmetic

Data:

```
DB1 <- data.frame(orderItemID  = 1:10,     
orderDate = c("2013-01-21","2013-03-31","2013-04-12","2013-06-01","2014-01-01", "2014-02-19","2014-02-27","2014-10-02","2014-10-31","2014-11-21"),  
deliveryDate = c("2013-01-23", "2013-03-01", "NA", "2013-06-04", "2014-01-03", "NA", "2014-02-28", "2014-10-04", "2014-11-01", "2014-11-23"))
```

Expected Outcome:

```
   DB1 <- data.frame(orderItemID  = 1:10,     
 orderDate= c("2013-01-21","2013-03-31","2013-04-12","2013-06-01","2014-01-01", "2014-02-19","2014-02-27","2014-10-02","2014-10-31","2014-11-21"),  
deliveryDate = c("2013-01-23", "2013-03-01", "2013-04-14", "2013-06-04", "2014-01-03", "2014-02-21", "2014-02-28", "2014-10-04", "2014-11-01", "2014-11-23"))
```

Hey guys, 
it´s me again ;) and unfortunately (I think) I have a pretty difficult question... As you can see above I have some missing values in the delivery dates and I want to replace them by another date. That date should be **the order date of the specific item + the average delivery time, in (full) days**. (In the example it's 1.75 days so that rounds to 2 days)
The average delivery time is the time calculated from the average value of all samples that do not contain Missing values = (2days+1day+3days+2days+1day+2days+1day+2days):8=1,75

so in a first step the average delivery time needs to be calculated an in the second step the order date + the average delivery time (in full days) needs to be entered instead of the NA´s

I tried already a little with [is.na(DB1$deliveryDate)] but unfortunately I have no good idea how to solve the problem...

Hope somebody got an idea

Comment: You should first convert these to real R Date vectors. Working with these in character form is just plain ... well, I won't say it.

Comment: Your example had typos, it needed `c(...)` on the deliveryDate line. Also, you're treating German-format dates as characters.

Comment: sorry-is quite late here: but I corrected it... hope you guys are able to help me

Comment: @Jarvis: it's very bad behavior on SO to multiply post the exact same question [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485858/fill-missing-date-values-in-column-by-adding-delivery-interval-to-another-date-c), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489749/replace-wrong-delivery-dates-in-dataset), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490669/replace-na´s-in-dates-with-another-date) times. That's grossly disrespectful to everybody's time. Don't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do date-arithmetic, and fill NAs in `deliveryDate` column by adding a date-interval of two days to `orderDate` column. `lubridate` supplies convenience functions for time intervals like `days(), weeks(), months(), years(), hours(), minutes(), seconds()` for exactly that purpose.
And first, you have to parse your (European-format) datestrings into R date objects.

Something like the following, using lubridate for date-arithmetic and dplyr for dataframe manipulation:

```
require(dplyr)

DB1$orderDate    = as.POSIXct(DB1$orderDate, format="%d.%m.%y", tz='UTC')
DB1$deliveryDate = as.POSIXct(DB1$deliveryDate, format="%d.%m.%y", tz='UTC')

DB1 %>% group_by(orderDate) %>%
        summarize(delivery_time = (deliveryDate - orderDate)) %>%
        ungroup() %>% summarize(median(delivery_time, na.rm=T))

# median(delivery_time, na.rm = T)
#                         1.5 days
# so you round up to 2 days
delivery_days = 2.0

require(lubridate)
DB1 <- DB1 %>% filter(is.na(deliveryDate)) %>%
                mutate(deliveryDate = orderDate + days(2))

# orderItemID  orderDate deliveryDate
#           3 2013-04-12   2013-04-14
#           6 2014-02-19   2014-02-21
```

Comment: this is not working (the second half with lubridate): Yes, it points out the ones with in NA at deliveryDate, and replace it with the correct date, but I want to correct it directly into the data set.

Comment: @Jarvis: you just need to assign `DB1 <- DB1 %>% filter ... mutate`. Fixed that.

Comment: @Jarvis: if you found any answer helpful (cough, cough), please [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)!

Comment: sorry- made it now :) I have another question  I uploaded a few mins ago: maybe you can also take a look at?! Thanks so much buddy!