# Replace wrong delivery dates in dataset

Tags: r

Data:

```
DB1 <- data.frame(orderItemID  = 1:10,     
orderDate = c("2013-01-21","2013-03-31","2013-04-12","2013-06-01","2014-01-01", "2014-02-19","2014-02-27","2014-10-02","2014-10-31","2014-11-21"),  
deliveryDate = c("2013-01-23", "2013-03-01", "2013-04-08", "2013-06-04", "2014-01-03", "2014-02-17", "2014-02-28", "2014-10-04", "2014-11-01", "2014-11-23"))
daysTillDelivery = c("2", "1", "-4", "3", "2", "-2", "1", "2", "1", "2")
```

Expected Outcome:

```
   DB1 <- data.frame(orderItemID  = 1:10,     
 orderDate= c("2013-01-21","2013-03-31","2013-04-12","2013-06-01","2014-01-01", "2014-02-19","2014-02-27","2014-10-02","2014-10-31","2014-11-21"),  
deliveryDate = c("2013-01-23", "2013-03-01", "NA", "2013-06-04", "2014-01-03", "NA", "2014-02-28", "2014-10-04", "2014-11-01", "2014-11-23"))
daysTillDelivery = c("2", "1", "NA", "3", "2", "NA", "1", "2", "1", "2")
```

Hey guys, 
unfortunately I have another problem I´m not able to solve alone... As you can see above I have some order dates, delivery dates and a function which calculates the days between order and delivery in days (numeric). This works fine so far, but as you can see, there are some incorrect delivery dates (the delivery date is earlier as the order date) so the number of days is negativ in some cases. Because it is not possible that the number of days is negative I would like to replace the delivery date by a "NA" , if a value is negative. When the value is positive the value should remain the original date.

I tried already sth like this:

```
DB1$deliveryDate <- ifelse(DB1$daysTillDelivery < 0 , DB1[c("deliveryDate")] <- "NA",  DB1$deliveryDate)
```

but this is not working properly...

Hope someone can help me with this :)

New expected outcome:

```
DB1 <- data.frame(orderItemID  = 1:10,     
 orderDate= c("2013-01-21","2013-03-31","2013-04-12","2013-06-01","2014-01-01", "2014-02-19","2014-02-27","2014-10-02","2014-10-31","2014-11-21"),  
deliveryDate = c("2013-01-23", "2013-03-01", "2013-04-14", "2013-06-04", "2014-01-03", "2014-02-21", "2014-02-28", "2014-10-04", "2014-11-01", "2014-11-23"))
daysTillDelivery = c("2", "1", "2", "3", "2", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2")
```

Comment: Jarvis it's very bad behavior on SO to multiply post the exact same question [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485858/fill-missing-date-values-in-column-by-adding-delivery-interval-to-another-date-c), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489749/replace-wrong-delivery-dates-in-dataset), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490669/replace-na´s-in-dates-with-another-date) times. That's grossly disrespectful to everybody's time. Don't do that.

Comment: There not the same there only very similar. But I try to do better next time :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a logical index using the negative values in 'daysTillDelivery'.  For some reason, it is a character vector, which we can convert to 'numeric'

```
  indx <- as.numeric(daysTillDelivery)<0
  is.na(DB1$deliveryDate) <- indx
```

Or

```
  DB1$deliveryDate[indx] <- NA
```

and the same for 'daysTillDelivery

```
  daysTillDelivery[indx] <- NA
```

#### Update

If we need the replace the 'deliveryDate' based on the negative values in 'daysTillDelivery',

```
  #convert the Date columns from 'factor' class to 'Date'
  DB1[-1] <- lapply(DB1[-1], as.Date)
  #add 2 to the subset of "orderDate" based on 'indx' and replace 
  #the corresponding values in 'deliveryDate' with that 
  DB1$deliveryDate[indx] <- as.Date(DB1$orderDate[indx])+2
```

Comment: What came up so far too: When I want to replace the NA´s in deliveryDate with the orderdate +2days now, what need to be done? Added some "new expected outcome" in questionaire

Comment: @Jarvis Updated with a possible solution.  Here, I am directly changing it to 'orderDate' +2 without the NA step.  If you need the intermediate step, use `indx <- is.na(DB1$orderDate)` and then use the last step.